# Perl - Iterate through hash of array values

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a data structure which I want to iterate through, then push to another array for temporary storage.

Each view in the hash has an array of fieldsets.

```
1 = {
   fieldset => ('package', 'payment'),
},

2 => {
   fieldset => ('address, 'review'),
}
3 => {
   fieldset => ('confirm'),
}
```

etc.

I want to grab all these values, and comma separate them into an another array, so I can see which steps the customer has left.

if I try

```
@array = $value->{fieldsets}
```

it only grabs the first item. How do I grab all of them?

Let me know if I haven't explained it in enough depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash values contain scalars.

```
1 = {
   fieldset => ('package', 'payment'),
},
```

flattens to:

```
1 = {
   fieldset => 'package',
   payment => undef,
},
```

You want:

```
1 = {
   fieldset => ['package', 'payment'],
},
```

To store an arrayref scalar, and access by dereferencing the contents of the fieldsets key:

```
@array = @{$value->{fieldset}}
```